# quotename(object_schema_name(@objectId)) returns null when called as a synonym

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a central utility database in each SQL Server instance, called `Utility`. In it, I have a bunch of centralized functions and procedures that I call from other databases.

A function I have in it is called `GetFqn`:

```
create function [dbo].[GetFqn](@objectId bigint)
returns varchar(100)
as
begin
    declare @fqn varchar(100);
    select @fqn = quotename(object_schema_name(@objectId)) + '.' + quotename(object_name(@objectId));
    return @fqn;
end
```

When I call this function from another database it returns `NULL`:

```
select Utility.dbo.GetFqn([object_id])
from sys.tables
```

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: How do you get [object_id]?

Comment: `[object_id]` is a field of `sys.tables`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a parameter which indicates a database:

```
create function [dbo].[GetFqn](@objectId bigint, @DatabaseId INT)
returns varchar(100)
as
begin
    declare @fqn varchar(100);
    select @fqn = quotename(object_schema_name(@objectId, @DatabaseId)) + '.' + quotename(object_name(@objectId, @DatabaseId));
    return @fqn;
end
```

Then call:

```
select Utility.dbo.GetFqn([object_id], DB_ID())
from sys.tables
```

Comment: In fact my hole purpose of creating this function is to reduce the amount of boilerplate code required for simple operations in SQL Server. While `db_id()` solves the problem, and I'm thankful for your answer, it would be counterproductive.